# trigonometric way to solve Sine and Cosine sums?

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

drawing graphs for most addition or subtractions of Sine and Cosine formula lead to another sine or cosine shaped graph, but I don't know how to actually write them as a formula.
For example , drawing plots of  "   $ a\ cos(\theta) -b \ sin(\theta) $ " and " $ a \ sin(\theta) + b \ cos(\theta) $ " both yield as sine-shaped graphs which means one should be able to write them in a form like :

$ a\ cos(\theta) -b \ sin(\theta) = A \ sin(\phi)$

or

$ a \ sin(\theta) + b \ cos(\theta) = B \ cos(\omega) $

but I can't think of a rational way of finding $ A,B, \phi \ and \  \omega$.   I highly appreciate if someone can shed light on this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are written with the same trigonometric function, you could find the value you are looking for by adding complex numbers.

First note that
$$\cos \theta = \sin \left(\theta + \frac\pi2\right)$$

If you want to find the sum of two sine funtions
$$a_1\sin(\theta + \phi_1) + a_2\sin(\theta + \phi_2)$$
you sum the complex numbers $a_1e^{i\phi_1}$ and $a_2e^{i\phi_2}$
$$a_1e^{i\phi_1} + a_2e^{i\phi_2} = Ae^{i\omega}$$
Then
$$a_1\sin(\theta + \phi_1) + a_2\sin(\theta + \phi_2) = A\sin(\theta +\omega)$$

---

Here an example
$$4\sin\theta + 3\cos\theta$$
We express both of them as sine
$$4\sin\theta + 3\sin\left(\theta+\frac\pi2\right)$$
Then, we sum the complex numbers $4e^{i0}$ and $3e^{i\frac\pi2}$
\begin{align}4 + 3e^{i\frac\pi2} &= 4 + 3\cos \frac\pi2 + 3i\sin\frac\pi2\\
 &= 4 + 3i\\
 &= 5e^{i\arctan\left(\frac34\right)}\end{align}
Finally
$$4\sin\theta+3\cos\theta = 5\sin\left(\theta+\arctan\left(\frac34\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Expand using the angle sum identity for $\sin$ i.e., write $$a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta = A \sin(\theta_0 + \theta) = A \cos \theta_0 \sin \theta + A \sin \theta_0 \cos \theta .$$ Now, match coefficients of $\sin \theta$, $\cos \theta$ to get
$$a = A \cos \theta_0, \qquad b = A \sin \theta_0 .$$
Solving for $A, \theta_0$ is now essentially converting from Cartesian to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$
\sin ( \alpha + \beta ) = \sin \alpha \cdot \cos \beta + \cos \alpha\cdot \sin \beta 
$$

Make a triangle with given constants a and b and use one of its angles to arrive at the answer. You could also use the formula for $ \cos (\alpha + \beta) $ to arrive at a result in terms of cos.